# How to express List value in List as jstl?

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

I solved the problem at the link below.

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47564537/how-to-display-existing-and-newly-created-values-in-el-in-spring-mvc)

The result is shown below.

```
model.addAttribute("commentList", commentList); 

commentList = [{board_comm_writer=Seongwon, board_comm_content=TEST, cocList=[{board_c_of_c_writer=Seongwon, board_c_of_c_content=hi everywon}]
```

I want to express the value of cocList with jstl.

As a result of my search for that method ...

```
<c:forEach items="${commentList}" var="cL">
  ${cL.cocList.board_c_of_c_content}
</c:forEach>
```

But this does not seem to be the right way.

To display cocList, How can I do that?

Comment: The answer is in the question. You use a forEach loop to iterate over its elements.

Comment: @JBNizet Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

I solve that.

```
<c:forEach items="${commentList}" var="cL">
 <c:forEach items="${cL.cocList} var="cLc">
   ${cLc.board_c_of_c_content}
 </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```